# Scanner() not working with if - else statement

Tags: string, if-statement, java.util.scanner

My intention is to let the user decide which method to use by cheking its input.

I have the following code:

```
try {
        String test = scan.next();
        if(test == "y") {
            //do stuff

        }
        else if (test == "n") {
            //do stuff
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

I tried to analyze with the debugger. It is not jumping in the `if`-statement.
can you help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `equals` to compare strings

```
if(test == "y")
```

becomes

```
if (test.equals("y"))
```

Same for `"n"` obviously.

`==` test for reference equality, but you're looking for value equality, that's why you should use `equals`, and not `==`.